# Assigning class to current image/slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

I am using fancybox 3 and need to assign a class to the current open slide

So far I have tried this, but unsuccesfully:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        afterMove: function( instance, slide ) {

            //tried this but none is working 
            $(this).addClass("active");
            slide.addClass("active");
            $(slide).addClass("active");    
        }
});
```

How can I assign a class to the current opened image? Do I have to use `$(slide)` or `slide` instead of `$(this)`?

Comment: did you checked by:- `instance.addClass("active");`?Also create a fiddle so that we can check and rectify your problem

Answer (score 1):

The DOM element containing your content would be `slide.$slide`